# How to delete a Json object in BASH

Tags: json, bash, gawk

I have a couple of Json objects and I need to delete  one of them if this Json contains specific information.  For an example I need to delete if state of the Json object is RUNNING.

INPUT

```
projects {
   key: "ads_evenflow.opt"
   value {
      name: "ads_evenflow.opt"
      state: COMPLETE
      result: PASSED
     }
 }
projects {
    key: "alexandria.opt"
    value {
      name: "alexandria.opt"
      state: RUNNING
      result: PASSED
    }
 }
    projects {
        key: "android.opt"
        value {
           name: "android.opt"
          state: COMPLETE
           result: PASSED
        }
  }
```

OUTPUT

```
  projects {
   key: "ads_evenflow.opt"
   value {
      name: "ads_evenflow.opt"
      state: COMPLETE
      result: PASSED
     }
  }
   projects {
        key: "android.opt"
        value {
           name: "androids.opt"
          state: COMPLETE
           result: PASSED
        }
  }
```

Comment: That syntax isn't actually JSON. Was it entered wrong in the question?

Comment: If it **were** JSON, this would be a trivial jq query, something like `select(.projects.value.state != "RUNNING")`.

Comment: (and *grumble* re: tagging the question `gawk` -- having a bunch of questions that have `awk` / `sed` / `tr` / kitchen-sink tags for tools the person asking them thinks might *possibly* be useful for a given purpose makes those tags less effective at filtering for questions actually *about* the tools themselves).

Comment: The title says that you want to do this in bash but bash doesn't natively parse JSON. Do you mean that you want a program you can run from the command line to do this? If you're really trying to do it in pure bash have you written any code to start? Edit your question to show the code you have so far and the output you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

Your structure **isn't** an valid `JSON`. For such structures you need some more *relaxed* parser. Fortunately, the [JSONY](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSONY) perl module could parse it. From the [doc](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSONY):

> JSONY is a data language that is simlar to JSON, just more chill. All
>   valid JSON is also valid JSONY (and represents the same thing when
>   loaded), but JSONY lets you omit a lot of the syntax that makes JSON a
>   pain to write.

The following perl code does what you want.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use 5.014;
use warnings;
use JSONY;

my $string = slurp_file();
my $data = JSONY->new->load( $string );
for my $proj (@{$data}) {
    next unless ref($proj);
    next if $proj->{value}->{state} eq 'RUNNING';
    pretty_print_proj($proj);
}

sub pretty_print_proj {
    my $p = shift;
    say "project {";
        say qq{\tkey: "$p->{key}"};
        say "\tvalue {";
            say "\t\t$_: ", $p->{value}->{$_} for (qw(name state result));
        say "\t}";
    say "}";
}

sub slurp_file {
    #change this for your real case...
    return do { local $/; <DATA>};
}

__DATA__
projects {
   key: "ads_evenflow.opt"
   value {
      name: "ads_evenflow.opt"
      state: COMPLETE
      result: PASSED
     }
 }
projects {
    key: "alexandria.opt"
    value {
      name: "alexandria.opt"
      state: RUNNING
      result: PASSED
    }
 }
    projects {
        key: "android.opt"
        value {
           name: "android.opt"
          state: COMPLETE
           result: PASSED
        }
  }
```

prints:

```
project {
    key: "ads_evenflow.opt"
    value {
        name: ads_evenflow.opt
        state: COMPLETE
        result: PASSED
    }
}
project {
    key: "android.opt"
    value {
        name: android.opt
        state: COMPLETE
        result: PASSED
    }
}
```